# Bootstrap list group item doesn't show when added from Javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a list group element in my application, I want to dynamically add
list group items from my Javascript code.

`mylistgroup` is an `ul` element with class `list-group`, inserted within a `div` like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul class="list-group" id="mylistgroup">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$("mylistgroup").append("<li class='list-group-item'>MY NEW ITEM</li>");
```

But it doesn't work ; nothing happens.

What am I missing ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `#` sign for `mylistgroup`.
Do following

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/86kL6/)**

```
$("#mylistgroup").append("<li class='list-group-item'>MY NEW ITEM</li>");
```

Comment: Glad to have helped . You can accept it answer if your problem is solved. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah ok no problem :)